# Excel VBA copy from one workbook into another

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I need to copy data from one workbook into another workbook.  The copy should be from cell A2 to the last cell used.  The paste should be into cell A2.

When I use this line I get an error.  Please help.  My head hurts!

```
  Workbooks("ClientData.xls").Worksheets("ClientInfo").Range("A2").SpecialCells(x1CellTypeLastCell).Address.Copy Workbooks("BGA Client Bio May2016v4.xlsm").Worksheets("ClientInfo").Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of specialcells you are using will only grab tha last cell not the whole range.

You also do not need or want the `Address`

This will do what you want

```
With Workbooks("ClientData.xls").Worksheets("ClientInfo")   
    .Range("A2",.Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Copy Workbooks("BGA Client Bio May2016v4.xlsm").Worksheets("ClientInfo").Range("A2")
End with
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I used your code and now I don't get an error, but it only copies and paste cell A2.

Comment: I got it.  I used this.  Thanks again so much for your helpWith Workbooks("ClientData.xls").Worksheets("ClientInfo")
    .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy Workbooks("BGA Client Bio May2016v4.xlsm").Worksheets("ClientInfo").Range("A2")

Comment: @JordanCA57 If Scott's answered your question, could you click the check mark by his answer to show everyone else that this is the answer, and to reward him for his effort in helping you?